# Do the credit bureaus have 14 or 30 days mortgage rate shopping window ?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, credit-score

I got prequalified 15 days ago. Now, I am planning to get prequalified with other lenders to compare the rates, and get a better deal with my mortgage APR rate. However, I'm worried that the credit bureaus will ding my credit score twice because I have missed that 14 days window.

I read many [articles online](http://www.myfico.com/crediteducation/creditchecks/inquiries.aspx). Some say it is a 14 days period, others - 30 days.

So, which one is it 14 or 30 ? Should I proceed with the rate shopping or not ? Will they ding my score twice if I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the link you offered:

> For FICO Scores calculated from older versions of the scoring formula,
>   this shopping period is any 14 day span. For FICO Scores calculated
>   from the newest versions of the scoring formula, this shopping period
>   is any 45 day span. Each lender chooses which version of the FICO
>   scoring formula it wants the credit reporting agency to use to
>   calculate your FICO Scores.

Keep in mind, there are two methods, so it's based on which the agency is using.